# add all links in div to another div with break using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addition, element

I'm trying to take the links from div links and add them to div links2 keeping the links in div links the way they are and the links in div links2 with a `<br />` after each link

What are you talking about!?!
ok lets take a look:

HTML:

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <a href="#">three</a>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="links2"></div>
```

JS:

```
var elements = $('#links a');
$('#results')
.text('there are ' + elements.length + ' links');
$('#links2').append(elements)
```

ok so ignore the results div, this is just showing how many links there are total.

right now i have append,  which is completely removing the links from div links.  how can I make it so it just adds the links to links2 with a br between each link.

So the final output would print something like this:

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <a href="#">three</a>
</div>
<div id="results">there are 3 links</div>
<div id="links2">
  <a href="#">one</a><br />
  <a href="#">two</a><br />
  <a href="#">three</a><br />
</div>
```

updated fiddle:(need to add br still)
http://jsfiddle.net/upLg4/44/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `.clone()` it before appending to other element,

```
$('#links2').append(elements.clone())
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vnopzexj/)

The object `elements` is referring a group of anchor tags inside `div#link`, so normally append will shift the elements from one place to other when it encounters an object referring other elements/a selector. That is why we have to clone it manually.

Comment: thank you =) is there anyway i can use this method to add a br between each link?

Comment: 6 minutes and i can accept it =) thank you so much so recap to copy content i have to clone it, and to add html I find tag and either before or after add what i need. (learning lol)

Answer (score 2):

Use `after()` method to add `<br>` after each link like following.

```js
var elements = $('#links a');
$('#results').text('there are ' + elements.length + ' links');
$('#links2').append(elements.clone());
$('#links2 a').after('<br />'); // use this line to add <br>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
    <a href="#">one</a>
    <a href="#">two</a>
    <a href="#">three</a>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="links2"></div>
```